# Using Latent Dirichlet Allocation on Contrived Data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, distributions, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

This is a cross-post of a post that was originally submitted to Math.Overflow

I am doing a project that seems like it might be susceptible to Latent Dirichlet Allocation. However, my data is highly contrived (both in test cases and use cases) and my "words" don't come close to following [Zipf's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law). When I try testing LDA, it doens't seem to work very well. The topics aren't particularly intelligible, and the list of words it spits out is just a list of the most common words in the corpus.

I've read a few papers on LDA, but I'm having trouble understanding (theoretically) the impact of the word distribution and how to modify the procedure to account for an unusual word distribution. The other obvious potential explanation is that I have a small number of unique words in my artificial corpus, but again I can't seem to find references on if that makes LDA inapplicable or what alternative to use.

If anyone has experience with this or references, I would appreciate an explanation at a theoretical level or on a code level.

Comment: Doesn't work well in terms of predicting held-out data, interpretability of the topics, or something else?

Comment: @SeanEaster oh, that's a good detail I left it. The issue is interpretability of topics. The list of key words it spits out are just the most common words in the corpus divided into groups.

Comment: It's impossible to comment helpfully on this without seeing what exactly you're trying to model and the contrived issues in your text dataset. At the very least, can you say how big your dataset is? The only thing I can think of is: have you tried playing around with the hyperparameters?: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/199/what-does-the-alpha-and-beta-hyperparameters-contribute-to-in-latent-dirichlet-a

Comment: That makes it a little harder to diagnose—interpretability is subjective, after all. And, LDA doesn't make any assumptions about the marginal distribution over words. Have you compared your model's predictive power against, say, a unigram model?